# Unable to substitute json from a file into a json data passed to curl in bash

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl

I have a CloudFormation script that contains a json content that I need to substitute for a json field within the post body or data of the curl POST request that I will make.

The CloudFormation file is like this:

```
{ "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09", "Description": 
...}
```

The problem is that I have tried some code below but it is not working.
However, I copy and past the content of the CloudFormation file into my POST request's body it works as expected. This implies that this is a substitution or scripting problem.

```
CLOUD_FORMATION_FILE=/home/developer/workspace/blah/blah/infrastructure/templates/component.json
template=`cat $CLOUD_FORMATION_FILE`
echo $template
curl -d '{"template": $(echo $template)}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://base.url.com/v1/services/component-proxy/test/stacks/test-component-proxy-component \
--cert /etc/pki/tls/certs/client.crt --key /etc/pki/tls/private/client.key
```

I am getting the error:

```
{"error": "Invalid JSON. Expecting object: line 1 column 13 (char 13)"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use double quotes in order to substitute a variable in a string.

There's no need to use `$(echo $variable)`, just use `$variable`.

```
curl -d "{\"template\": $template}" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://base.url.com/v1/services/component-proxy/test/stacks/test-component-proxy-component \
--cert /etc/pki/tls/certs/client.crt --key /etc/pki/tls/private/client.key
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. This worked. However, you need to update your response by replacing the last single quote with double quotes. Thank you very much. It should be ```"{\"template\": $template}"```

Comment: @barmer, I will mark this as the answer. Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: I want to inject variables from pipeline in the template but it don't work there :(

Comment: Write a new question that shows what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69396104/substitute-azure-variables-in-the-json-file-called-from-bash-script